# Making a copy constructor more flexible for ADT queue

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, constructor

I have constructed a copy constructor for an ADT queue. The copy constructor works fine. I would want to improve my code, but I don't really know how to shorten it to make it more flexible.

```
template <typename T>
Queue <T>::Queue(const Queue & other)
{
    if (other.first == nullptr)
    {
        first = nullptr;
        nrOfElements = 0;
    }

   else
   {
    Node* saveFirst;
    Node* walker;
    first = other.first;
    walker = new Node(first->data);
    saveFirst = walker;
    while (first->next != nullptr)
    {
        walker->next = new Node(first->next->data);
        walker = walker->next;
        first = first->next;
    }
    walker->next = nullptr;
    first = saveFirst;
    }
this->nrOfElements = other.nrOfElements;
}
```

The class `Queue` also contains an inner private `Node` class which contains the pointers `first`, `next`, etc:

```
private:
    int nrOfElements;
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node* next;
        T data;
        Node(T data)
        {
            this->data = data;
        }
    };
    Node* first;
```

So, I would appreciate any suggestions/examples of how the copy constructor code above could be improved, as I'm a bit lost on the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remove redundancy

> ```
>    {
>     Node* saveFirst;
>     Node* walker;
>     first = other.first;
>     walker = new Node(first->data);
>     saveFirst = walker;
>     while (first->next != nullptr)
>     {
>         walker->next = new Node(first->next->data);
>         walker = walker->next;
>         first = first->next;
>     }
>     walker->next = nullptr;
>     first = saveFirst;
>     }
> this->nrOfElements = other.nrOfElements;
> ```

You create a temporary variable `saveFirst`.  You then use a class field as temporary variable.  When done, you set the class field to the value set in the temporary variable.  Why not do it the other way around?

```
   {
       Node* current = new Node(other.first->data);
       first = current;

       for (Node *otherCurrent = other.first; otherCurrent->next != nullptr; otherCurrent = otherCurrent->next)
       {
           current->next = new Node(otherCurrent->next->data);
           current = current->next;
       }

       current->next = nullptr;
       nrOfElements = other.nrOfElements;
    }
```

This uses the temporary variable to hold the changing `current` variable.  It sets `first` to the correct value immediately and directly.  It changes the loop to say for every node in `other`.  Now you don't have to set the class field at the end.

Note that I also moved the number of elements assignment inside the `else`.  In the original it would have tried to dereference a null `other`.

### Reuse other methods

You don't mention other functions in the class, but there are certain ones that could be used here (assuming C++11).

```
    {
        for (auto i : other)
        {
            this.append(i.data);
        }
    }
```

This would replace the entire `else` block.  If you have to create the `begin`, `end`, and `append` functions anyway, then this drops the amount of code that you have to maintain considerably.  Note that `begin` and `end` are required to make the range-based `for` loop work.